# Ошибка при попытке запуска кода через maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eclipse, maven

Заранее предупреждаю, очень много букв

Пересоздаю вопрос со всеми обновлениями. Запускаю всё в IntelliJ IDEA используя maven. Проблема в том, что при использовании некоторых библиотек всё крашится:

Вызываю с помощью следующей строчки:

```
exec:java -e -Dexec.mainClass="Main"
```

Изначально был такой набор:

POM:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <groupId>actticus</groupId>
    <artifactId>instDBParse</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.igor-suhorukov</groupId>
            <artifactId>instagramscraper</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.devcolibri.core.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-selenium</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Main:

```
import me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.Instagram;
import me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.model.Tag;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Instagram instagram = new Instagram(httpClient);
        Tag tags;
        try
        {
            tags = instagram.getMediasByTag("snow", 1000);
            System.out.println(tags.getCount());
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

B ошибка, как я понял была в том, что не хватало в зависимостях javax/xml/bind

Код ошибки:

```
    Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project instDBParse: An exception occured while executing the Java class. javax/xml/bind/JAXBException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project instDBParse: An exception occured while executing the Java class. javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.Instagram.<init>(Instagram.java:25)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 8 more
```

После этого я добавил эту зависимость:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Пересобрал и вызвал, сначала появились красные warning'и:

```
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by okhttp3.internal.Platform (file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.2.0/okhttp-3.2.0.jar) to field sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.context
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of okhttp3.internal.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Сразу за ними шло следующее сообщение:

```
    [EL Warning]: moxy: 2019-03-14 00:37:30.684--MOXy BV: Facets generation could not be configured. EclipseLink's JavaModelInputImpl was not detected, instead JavaModelInput is of class: class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.oxm.OXMJavaModelInputImpl
[WARNING] 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)]
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.mapper.ModelMapper.mapObject(ModelMapper.java:180)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.mapper.ModelMapper.mapTag(ModelMapper.java:77)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.request.GetMediaByTagRequest.mapResponse(GetMediaByTagRequest.java:55)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.request.GetMediaByTagRequest.mapResponse(GetMediaByTagRequest.java:13)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.request.PaginatedRequest.requestInstagramResult(PaginatedRequest.java:39)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.Instagram.getMediasByTag(Instagram.java:147)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:172)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.mapper.ModelMapper.mapObject(ModelMapper.java:178)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.unmarshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:156)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.unexpectedChar(JsonTokenizer.java:532)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$NoneContext.getNextEvent(JsonParserImpl.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.next(JsonParserImpl.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.read(JsonReaderImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:138)
    ... 18 more
[WARNING] thread Thread[OkHttp ConnectionPool,5,Main] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[OkHttp ConnectionPool,5,Main] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[Okio Watchdog,5,Main] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 2 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=Main,maxpri=10]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy(ThreadGroup.java:776)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:321)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

Ну и сами ошибки:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project instDBParse: An exception occured while executing the Java class. javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
[ERROR] - with linked exception:
[ERROR] [Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
[ERROR] Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
[ERROR] Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project instDBParse: An exception occured while executing the Java class. javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)]
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.mapper.ModelMapper.mapObject(ModelMapper.java:180)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.mapper.ModelMapper.mapTag(ModelMapper.java:77)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.request.GetMediaByTagRequest.mapResponse(GetMediaByTagRequest.java:55)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.request.GetMediaByTagRequest.mapResponse(GetMediaByTagRequest.java:13)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.request.PaginatedRequest.requestInstagramResult(PaginatedRequest.java:39)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.Instagram.getMediasByTag(Instagram.java:147)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:172)
    at me.postaddict.instagram.scraper.mapper.ModelMapper.mapObject(ModelMapper.java:178)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.unmarshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:156)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 60 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.unexpectedChar(JsonTokenizer.java:532)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$NoneContext.getNextEvent(JsonParserImpl.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.next(JsonParserImpl.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.read(JsonReaderImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:138)
    ... 18 more
```

Уже перерыл гугл, полезной информации найти не смог, пытаюсь найти способ, чтобы это заработало

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у Вас приходит невалидный JSON и библиотека instagram-java-scraper просто падает при попытке его распарсить и создать java объекты

Comment: @Sergi Ладно, спасибо, сейчас напишу на гитх создателю либы

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Данная библиотека не работает на Java 11. Проблема в том, что Eclipse в Java 11 парсит JSON иначе, чем при Java 8. Смените Java 11 JDK на Java 8 и всё будет работать.